# Export JanusGraph graph image into Excel

Tags: python, excel, janusgraph, jupyterhub

I'm using JanusGraph in Jupyter Notebook.  I'm currently looking to export my results into Excel.  I'm able to export out the data, but not the graph image itself.

At the moment, I'm just manually cut/pasting the image into Excel.  Is there any way to automate that?

Comment: In short, you mean you're working directly from Jupyter, yes? It looks like the standard export format is JSON, and there will be a node with your image data. This may be a useful read: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/export-images-from-jupyter-notebook-with-a-single-command-422db2b66e92

Comment: Here is the same author's github with their python export project. https://github.com/damienmarlier51/Junix  If you've already been there, or have other solutions you have tried, edit your question to provide a bit more detail.